# How to process geometry messages of type PoseWithCovarianceStamped and PoseStampe

Tags: ros, ros-info, amcl-pose, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS fuerte version on Ubuntu 10.04.

I have a **screen shot below (WHOLE TOPIC.jpg)** which tells about what type of messages are published on topics  amcl_pose and move_base_simple/goal :

[WHOLE TOPIC.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13987978633578358.jpg)

Messages of **amcl_pose** are passed to a callback function,called **currentPosCallback**

```
void CmdVelMux::currentPosCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
{      
 double xPos;
 double yPos;
 double zPos;
 xPos = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
 ROS_INFO("the position value is %lf \n ",xPos);
}
```

Messages of **move_base_simple/goal** are passed to a callback function,called **goalPosCallback**

```
void CmdVelMux::goalPosCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
{      
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;   
    x = msg->pose.position.x;
    y = msg->pose.position.y;
   z = msg->pose.position.z;
   ROS_INFO("the position value is %lf \n ",x);
}
```

**Question 1**:I want to **calculate angle** between **current goal(from move_base_simple/goal topic) and robot position (amcl_pose)**.

In trigonometry, we can calculate **angle between two points P1(x1,y1) and P2(x2,y2)**. Is there any way to do this type of thing here?

I want to store this angle in class member data, what is the guarantee that it is the **most updated one**?

How to do that?

Thanks for any kind of help................

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158761/how-to-process-geometry-messages-of-type-posewithcovariancestamped-and-posestampe/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could:

1. Declare member variables, say goalX, goalY, robotX, and robotY.
2. In the callbacks, store the values in the appropriate variables.
3. When you want to calculate the angle, just do `atan2(goalY - robotY, goalX - robotX)`.

As for your question regarding guaranteeing that you are working with the most recent data, every time ROS does a spin, it processes all the callbacks sequentially, so your loop goes like this:

```
while(ros::ok())
{
  ros::spinOnce(); // Callbacks are processed here

  double angle = ::atan2(goalY - robotY, goalX - robotX);
  ...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-30**:
Thanks for the answer @Tom Moore